# Change window command prompt string

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to change the command prompt string in a windows command prompt?

For example.

C:\current\path -> $CustomPrompt>

If possible, I would prefer the solution to make use of the winapi. I already looked at
some of the console functions, but I cannot find any that I would assume wold manipulate the prompt string? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with just setting the [`PROMPT` environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028372/how-to-change-command-line-prompt-in-windows)?

Comment: I'm writing a C++ program so, if possible, I would like to stick to using c++. Oh, as a correction, PROMPT isn't a environment variable, it's a command.

Comment: @user246694 Your are wrong. PROMPT is both an environmental variable and DOS/Windows command which sets this variable.

Comment: How am I wrong, if I am indeed referring to the command? You stated yourself that it is a command that sets the variable.

Comment: use the `prompt` command, unless you want to change the default at the user or system level, in which case use the System control panel applet.

Comment: Like I said, I would prefer if it to done in C++. What is the "System control panel applet.?

Comment: @user246694 you were wrong when you stated that 'PROMPT isn't a environment variable'

Comment: Well, context wise, I was not. I might not have known that there was indeed a variable with the same name that were related to each other. But then again, I will still only referring to the command. Now, however, I have learned that there is environment variable also with the same name. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you write a program to do something that the system already has fully functional tools for?

Comment: That actually isn't that main feature of the program. The program actually does something else. But I wanted to change the prompt when the program is initiated. Thought it would neat to have the program do that a la the "netsh" command.

Comment: There's no supported way to do this to your parent command interpreter.  The console functions won't help: they're for manipulating the console, not the command interpreter.

Comment: From what point of view do you want to do this? A CLI application running in said command prompt? a parent process creating a command prompt/console window? a random 3rd party process?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean? I believe i'm trying to do the first option.

Comment: @agentNil please see edits to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Command Prompt String is definied as environmental variable PROMPT. You can modify this variable using `setenv()` function from `cstdlib` :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

setenv("PROMPT", "$A$A", true);
```

This will, for example, set prompt string to '&&' (double ampersand). For more interesting examples check [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx) out.

EDIT: There is a way to achieve this **without** need to restart command interpreter. Create following batch file:

```
@echo off
break off
title custom command prompt
color 0a
cls

:cmd
 set /p cmd=command:

 %cmd%
 echo.
 goto cmd
```

Lets name it "change_prompt.bat" Then, in your c++ code execute the batch file:

```
system("change_prompt.bat");
```

As a result, prompt will look like this:

[image: new prompt]

As you can see, this changes:

- prompt window title
- prompt color
- prompt string

Comment: unless this is a silly rep-harvesting maneuver, the OP should note that this only affects the prompts of command interpreter instances created (later on) by this process, and remove the "solution" selection

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Corrected. Well, I am aware this is not a good choice. If you have some better one, feel free to post it.

Comment: re the header just use <stdlib.h>. re the function, i'm sorry i didn't notice that it's Posix, not C++ std. so the correction you did was in the wrong direction, just remove the `std::` (it's not a standard function), use `stdlib.h`, and note that it's a Posix function.

Comment: I was thinking maybe to just settle for the std::system from <cstdlib> and call std::system("Prompt myprompt");

Comment: @agentNil: no, that would only affect the command shell started by the call to `system`, which would exit without doing anything else.

Comment: How then are programs like netsh or git able to change the prompt? That's what I'm trying to mimic.

Comment: @agentNil I edited an answer by adding new solution. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Kao Okay, i'll check out tomorrow. Thanks. Looks promising.