# Is there a way to hide the vs code full directory path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

It seems just so distracting to show all this, while you run a program. Is there a way to hide all this path information? I installed vs code with c++ extensions, i think i probably double installed something because it likes to show everything, all the paths available.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87J1.jpg)

Comment: Move your program location to C:\ and that's it.

Comment: VSCode uses `cmd.exe`, and `cmd.exe` shows the entire path just by default. You don't appear to have done anything wrong. I don't have a Windows computer on hand to test, so I won't answer, but see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12028372/5684257), the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration) and the [`cmd.exe` docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) for how to change the prompt. Also, @RohanBari, that's one of the least helpful comments I've seen on this site in a long while...

Comment: This ensures that the commands always work no matter what your current working directory is.

Comment: @HTNW VSCode allows you to choose any shells you want, by default it's PowerShell and not cmd. But any shells will show the current directory in the prompt including bash, ksh, zsh... Hiding the cwd doesn't do any good

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the command-line prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028372/how-do-i-change-the-command-line-prompt-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the command line directory is there to stay, i also dont like that it will list sometimes up to 3 directories, but if im stuck with it, then it is what it is..thanks everybody

Comment: @phuclv It's only Powershell on Windows 10 and up (which it says right there on the docs I linked). It looked like `cmd.exe` to me, so I posted its docs, but actually, now that I look at it, it does say "Windows 10", so I suppose it is Powershell.